# Can/should multiple custom directives be applied to the same element in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

In my app I have a custom directive, written by someone else) that validates and formats several different form fields (ex. name, address, phone, credit card number, DOB, etc). If the user inputs invalid data, `ng-invalid` is added to that particular form element's CLASS attribute. There is a function bound to the **submit** of the form that checks to see if all fields contain valid data before allowing it to submit. Something like

```
  app.directive('validateForms', function () {

      var form = angular.element(elem);
      scope.isSubmitted = false;

      form.bind('submit', function() {
          scope.isSubmitted = true;
          if(form.hasClass('ng-invalid')) return false;
       });
  });
```

And this directive is applied to the  element in the view.

```
<form name="request-info" id="request-info" validate-forms>
```

I have been tasked with displaying error messages below the fields containing invalid data. My thinking is that I should create a 2nd directive that applies the error messages so that different validation directives and different error display directives can be used on the various forms within the app.

So in a 2nd directive, I'm trying to $watch something that tells me the form has been submitted and to display error messages where necessary. I tried to set a variable, isSubmitted, that would change to TRUE onsubmit, but the 2nd directive doesn't seem to be seeing when that variable changes.

```
app.directive('showErrMsgs', ['$timeout',
        function($timeout) {
            return {
                restrict : 'A',
                link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.$watch('isSubmitted', function () {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            alert(scope.isSubmitted);
                            // call function to display error messages
                        });
                    });
            }
        };
}]);
```

And this directive is applied to the  element in the view.

```
<form name="request-info" id="request-info" validate-forms show-err-msgs>
```

The expected behavior was that clicking the submit button would change the value of isSubmitted and trigger the alert() with its value (for now). Sadly, there was no alert at all... which leads me to believe one or both of the following:

1. the 2 directives are in different scopes and that's why changes in one are not being detected in the other
2. I'm going about this completely wrong and it can't be done like this.

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps scope.$apply()? You're also missing the ,0 timeout delay  `},0);`. You may want to communicate between directives with a service - a service is basically the pointer concept - both will reference the same thing, when that thing changes, everyone gets notified.

Answer (score 0):

Uuuuugh, **so** stupid!! I had the 1st directive as part of my "Validate" module:

`angular.module('validator').directive(...`

and the 2nd directive as part of my main module.

`angular.module('buyApp').directive(...`

When both directives were attached to the "Validate" module, the code in my original post works. I'd still like to know if this is a prudent approach to form validation and displaying error messages. Anyone?